# Maven PMD Plugin 3.3 with vm and xml rule sets

Tags: xml, maven, xslt, velocity, pmd

I work with the version 3.3 of Maven PMD Plugin. It uses PMD 5.2.1.

With this pluging, the avaible rule sets are defined by:

- net.sourceforge.pmd:pmd-core
- net.sourceforge.pmd:pmd-java
- net.sourceforge.pmd:pmd-javascript
- net.sourceforge.pmd:pmd-jsp

I was able to define a custom rule set file using some of those rule sets :

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${pmd.maven.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>${skip.pmd}</skip>
                    <!-- 
                    <targetJdk>${maven.compiler.target}</targetJdk>
                     -->
                    <linkXRef>true</linkXRef>
                    <aggregate>false</aggregate>
                    <skipEmptyReport>false</skipEmptyReport>
                    <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
                    <includeXmlInSite>true</includeXmlInSite>
                    <rulesets>
                        <ruleset>${project.parent.basedir}/../build-config/src/main/resources/docsite/build/config/pmd-java.xml</ruleset>
                    </rulesets>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

Now I'd like to add the rule sets defined by:

- net.sourceforge.pmd:pmd-vm
- net.sourceforge.pmd:pmd-xml

The pages:

- Using Rule Sets
  http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/examples/usingRuleSets.html
- Analyzing JavaScript Code
  http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/examples/javascriptReport.html

seem outdated and didn't help.

Any help will be appreciated.

Update:

About the page "Analyzing JavaScript Code" example: inside a reporting, dependencies can be declared under configuration only, not directly under a plugin declaration. So yes, IMO this page is not up to date.

With the dependency at the right location, everything runs fine, but the dependency is useless as net.sourceforge.pmd:pmd-javascript is embedded with maven-pmd-plugin. 
So the example works very well with or without any dependency declaration.

Now with the ruleset "vm-basic", nothing works. As net.sourceforge.pmd:pmd-vm is not embedded with maven-pmd-plugin, a dependency declaration is needed, i.e.:

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <rulesets>
                    <ruleset>vm-basic</ruleset>
                </rulesets>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.sourceforge.pmd</groupId>
                        <artifactId>pmd-vm</artifactId>
                        <version>5.2.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

generates this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.4:site (default-site) on project stage-plugin1: Execution default-site of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.4:site failed. NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
```

As soon as I remove the ruleset "vm-basic", everything runs fine, but no pmd report...

Comment: What problem are you having? The first page you linked has a date of 11/14/2014 which doesn't seem out of date to me?

Comment: Both pages have the same date cause they have been released at the same time. As mentioned 11/14/2014...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven PMD plug-in not generating a report with 'mvn site' command or 'pmd:pmd'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28775835/maven-pmd-plug-in-not-generating-a-report-with-mvn-site-command-or-pmdpmd)