# Maven: Unable to generate PMD report using pmd:pmd

Tags: maven, maven-3, pmd

I am not able to generate a PMD report in any format. Even after setting the `<skipEmptyReport>` attribute to false, I am not able to get the PMD report in any format. I am not able to know the reason why is it so?

I have already reviewed [Maven PMD plug-in not generating a report with 'mvn site' command or 'pmd:pmd'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28775835/maven-pmd-plug-in-not-generating-a-report-with-mvn-site-command-or-pmdpmd) but it didn't help me. Are there any solutions for this?

Comment: Have you added the necessary pluigin your pom.xml http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3.0/mvn-plugin.html

Comment: yes.I have added that plugin.

Comment: what do you get when you execute pmd:pmd, and have you given the output and target directories correctly where you want http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/pmd-mojo.html

Comment: Fixed the parameter name to <skipEmptyReport>.

Comment: Thanks.It got fixed.can somebody tell me that how do i ensure whether custom ruleset file is used or not?I got the custom ruleset file on classpath.i but I doubt that mvn pmd:pmd is not using my custom ruleset file.